# How to use a specific version of dll from a package that contains two versions of the same assembly and is being pulled in by a PackageReference

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-4.8, packagereference

I have a .sln that has two different .csprojs in it (amongst others), one of the .csprojs uses an earlier version of a particular dll and the other ,csproj uses a later version of the dll. Right now, these assemblies are committed into two different separate directories and the projects are pulling them from there. I'd like to remove these assemblies from having to be committed to source control and instead pull them in via a nuget package using . So, I created a nuget package that has both these assemblies in it (version 1x and version 2x) where the nuspec for the package has something like this in it:

`<file src=".\bin\foo.dll" target="lib\net48" /> <file src=".\bin\v2\foo.dll" target="lib\net48\v2" />`

but now I'm having difficulties on how I tell the .csprojs to use the specific versions of the dll that they need. I know using packages.config I could use a hint path to differentiate between the two, but I'd prefer to use a  to pull these assemblies in. Anyone have any ideas?

I tried using the nuget package I created, but it didn't seem like the csprojects were able to differentiate between the assemblies. I'm also aware that this problem could be solved using packages.config with specific `<HintPath>`'s, but I don't want to go that route.

Comment: That makes little sense, create two nuget packages instead.